# Rings: If any (right or left) cancellation law holds, then other cancellation law holds

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If right cancellation law holds, then is it neccessary that left cancellation law must also hold?

I searched over the internet but couldn't find any source claiming that this statement is true, but seems like it should be true.

Here's my reasoning: If RCL holds, then there can be no zero divisors. Hence both cancellation laws must hold true.

If it is not the case, can someone provide with a counter example?

Comment: What are zero divisors in a group? Take the cyclic group $C_n=\{e,g,g^2,\ldots ,g^{n-1}\}$. If you only consider rings, then the ring need not be commutative. So we need to distinguish right and left zero divisors.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what my confusion is.
Zero divisors of a ring exist if there exists non zero a and non zero b s.t. ab = 0

So if ab=0
=> ab = 0b

(as a and b should be non zero, apply RCL and cancel out b)

=> a = 0

=> contradiction

=> There can be no non zero a and non zero b s.t. ab = 0
=>  Ring has no zero divisors
=> LCL holds

Where exactly am I getting this wrong?

Comment: You are essentially right, and are giving (nearly) the arguments suggested at the duplicate.  See the linked *solutions* rather than the linked question.